# Printing a char in ANSI C

Tags: c

I've used getchar and putchar to succeessfully print my entered char to the screen before, however I've changed the code slightly and now it prints my entered char twice in a row. Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int charInput;
    printf("Enter a char >> ");
    charInput = getchar();
    printf("%c", putchar(charInput));

    return 0;
}
```

I know I could just use putchar without the printf but I wanted to experiment with them. The output I get is:

```
Enter a char >> a
aa
```

2 chars are printed to the screen?

Comment: `putchar` returns the passed argument on success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`putchar(charInput)` will print your character once, and will then return its argument,
`charInput`. This then gets passed to `printf`, which prints the same character again.

Answer (score 4):

The function `putchar(charInput)` itself print char `'a'` and return decimal equivalent of char (e.g ascii) that is printed as char using `printf()` so total printed two `a`.

Read [Manual page:](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/putchar/)

> `int putchar(int c);`
>
> The functions, `fputc()`, `putc()`, `putchar()`, `putc_unlocked()`, and 
>   `putchar_unlocked()` **return the character written**.  If an error
>   occurs, the  value `EOF` is returned.  The `putw()` function returns 0 on
>   success; `EOF` is  returned if a write error occurs, or if an attempt is
>   made to write a  read-only stream.

So you can assume:

```
printf("%c", putchar(charInput));
//      ^            ^ first `a` 
//      | second `a`
```

is equivalent to:

```
temp = putchar(charInput);  // first `a`
printf("%c", temp);         // second `a`
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because one comes from`printf` and another from `putchar`.
Do only this

```
putchar(charInput);
```