# Nested printf in my exam

Tags: c, printf, nested

The exact code snippet that appeared in my exam was :

```
int main()
{ 
  int n=234;
  printf("%d,",printf("%d",n));
}
```

According to what I got when I compiled the code the answer came out to be : `"2343,"`
For the explanation I asked my friend and he said that the outermost `printf()` gives the number of digits in the number...
Is that true? Can someone explain?

Comment: What does your coumentation for printf suggest?

Comment: This is tagged C, so one shall link C man pages: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html

Comment: Read [Printing a char in ANSI C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387100/printing-a-char-in-ansi-c/19387118#19387118)

Comment: Printf returns `number of char it prints` on console/stdout, and inner printf  `printf("%d",n)` prints `3` chars `2`, `3`, `4` so return `3` that is printed by outer printf. Note: Outer printf prints only two chars `3` and `,` so it returns `2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf` returns the number of characters printed if succeeded.
So, In your example, you have in `n` variable a numbe consisted of 3 digits (it corresponds to 3 characters if printed), so the nested printf will return 3 after printing out `n`. and this will be printed from the outter print.
([more](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html))

Comment: This question is tagged C not C++.

Comment: @alk Answer Updated, although the same function is used in both C and C++.

Answer (score 4):

That code is the same as :

```
int n=234;
int k = printf("%d",n);
printf("%d,",k);
```

If you now know what [printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/printf.html) returns, you can easily deduce what will be printed out by this program.

Answer (score 1):

From the manpage for printf (also available, say, at http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

```
Return Value
   Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters printed
   (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings).
```

Therefore yes, it is true. You can always debug the code to make sure for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes printf returns the number of characters printed, see for example

<s>http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/</s>

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html

So in this case first the inner *printf* prints the value of *n* to the screen (234), and then it returns 3 (=three characters), which is turn printed by the outer *printf*.  There is a comma at the end, so finally the printed string is '2343,'

Comment: This question is tagged C not C++.

Comment: ok changed it.. even though they are actually the same function afaik.